# Modul should show modal/UIViewController in main thread but it doesnt work without delay

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-modules

I trying to present UIViewController in my React native app from Swift module
I am presenting it like this

```
  let screen = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
  screen?.rootViewController?.present(payController!, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

and I get this error:
`UIApplication.windows must be used from main thread only`

ok I have to add it to my thread

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let screen = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    screen?.rootViewController?.present(payController!, animated: true, completion: nil);
  }
```

and it works fine when I call this function with small delay

```
setTimeout(() => {
  showMyWiew();
}, 500);
```

or delay into swift like this

```
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    let screen = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    screen?.rootViewController?.present(payController!, animated: true, completion: nil);
  }
```

but if I remove the delay then this modal is not shown. But it should be there. and i see this in log in swift which confirms my theory:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <PKAddPaymentPassViewController: 0x103d6b2e0> on <UIViewController: 0x103c25480> (from <UIViewController: 0x103c25480>) which is already presenting <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x10e21df40>.
```

`PKAddPaymentPassViewController` is my UIViewController

I don't know how to fix this issue...

**UPDATE**

Based on first comment I did this

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let screen = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    let controller = screen?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController;
    if controller == nil {
      screen?.rootViewController?.present(payController!, animated: true, completion: nil);
    } else {
      screen?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(payController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

  }
```

and the good news is the modal will show up but immediately is close I see the open effect and then close effect ...

**SOLUTION**

1. all in the update section
2. refactoring RN code
   It turned out There is open another modal before this new.  The old modal is not closed before I open the new one ... so I close the old modal faster and then I show new and all is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because at that exact moment `screen?.rootViewController` seems to already present another ViewController (`RCTModalHostViewController`). A VC that is already presenting some VC *can not* present yet another VC. What you could do is to call present on the VC that is being presented by the rootViewController at that moment: `screen?.rootViewController.presentedViewController?.present(...)`. (Presenting on a presented ViewController does work. Presenting on a VC that presents another VC does not.)

If you do that you should also make sure that `presentedViewController` is actually set and not `nil`. If it is nil you can just call present on `rootViewController` as you did earlier.

Comment: Thank you ... the good news is the modal will show up but immediately is close I see the open effect and then close effect ... check my update... can you help me with this issue also?

Comment: Then it probably depends on the actual situation you're trying to present. It seems to me that the `presentedViewController` is just about to be dismissed when you call `present`. When the `presentedViewController` gets dismissed it will also dismiss anything that it presents in turn. So that would explain both your initial problem and the new one.
Two ways to fix this: 1) find a better place in the code to call `present` Or 2) make sure that the `presentedViewController` does not get dismissed at that moment. I don't know how much influence you have here with react native though...

Comment: i tried to add it on another place but doesn't work... now I am playing with `   `controller?.isModalInPresentation = true` this work ... but I can not use cancel button in modal .... any idea why?

Comment: If the timing issue is a limitation by the module you're using with react native, I think you'll have to look for a completely different approach of getting the view out. Maybe not use a modal?

Comment: it is `add card to apple wallet` and apple force us to use this modal ...

Comment: after some refactoring, it works ... thanks